# Left-child, right-sibling expression tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, tree

I'm completely stuck on one of my assignments, and could use some help.

We're implementing a tree class, which stores and evaluates a binary expression. Here is an example of one such expression: (MAJ (AND 3 4) (OR 1 2 3) (NOT 5) 4 ). This refers to this tree:
[image: sample tree]

The tree is given to us in the LCRS representation, and we're building a class to perform various operations on it, such as finding the largest number in the tree, finding the number of a particular operator, or printing the original formula that resulted in the given tree. And I've figured out all of those, through hours of head-scratching and stacks of paper used to trace large recursive functions.

But I can't figure out the last required function, which is

```
bool evaluate(const vector<bool> &values, Tree_Node* p)
```

This function evaluates the expression, using truth values provided by the vector of bools (for example, if values[3] and values[4] are both true, then (AND 3 4) would be true). I've spent a bunch of time looking for answers, and thought I was onto something with expression trees, but can't find anything about how it works in the LCRS representation.

I just can't figure out the recursion. I've split it into all the possible cases, but there's a lot of those when you take the different operators into account. To try to keep it succinct, I'll say that my primary question is:

How do I evaluate each subtree? For example, in the LCRS tree, the

```
 AND
 /
3
 \
  4
```

I see that I need to get down to the 4, realize it's the simplest (base) case, and then begin recursing back up to the AND, but I don't see how to get the right value when I get back to the AND. Do I need an extra parameter or something? Maybe passing down the operation, or using some kind of following extra pointer?

//Some clarification stuff

The four operators are:

- MAJ - returns true if the majority of the inputs are true
- AND - logical AND (true if both inputs are true)
- OR - logical OR
- NOT - negation

(assuming the people on SO understand and, or, & not.)

The Node struct is a stereotypical one:

```
struct Tree_Node {  
    std::string data;
    Tree_Node* left_child;
    Tree_Node* right_sibling;
}
```

The Tree class is standard as well except for the additional functions for the assignment,
I can post code if necessary, but it has the operations you would expect of a Tree, and compiles and tests properly, the question is only regarding this function.

I'm banging my head on my desk between this and my other homework... oh, the life of a CS major. Any help, as always, is much appreciated.

Edit:

Huge thanks to everyone who helped me out. All of the answers I got here really helped me figure things out. Sometimes it helps to get a fresh perspective. Also, std::pair is new to me! Funny, because I have a templated class of my own that does the same exact thing... guess that it's time to retire that guy!

I will post my function and analysis here when I've finished the assignment, for future reference.

Edit:
As promised, the completed function. count_children is functionally identical to the count function laid out by rici, and TruthValues is a std::pair of ints, like Counts. Thanks again to those who helped me figure this out. The function switch_help returns the appropriate number for the switch statement when given a string (e.g. `switch_help("MAJORITY") == 2`).

```
bool BooleanFormula::evaluate(const vector<bool> & values, Tree_Node* p){

    TruthValues truth_vals = TruthValues(0,0);
    int control = switch_help(p->data);

    switch (control){
        case 1: //p->data = "MAJORITY"
            truth_vals = count_children(values, p->left_child);
            return (truth_vals.first > truth_vals.second);
            //return true if there are more trues than falses

        case 2: //p->data = "AND"
            truth_vals = count_children(values, p->left_child);
            return (truth_vals.second == 0);
            //return true if there are no falses

        case 3: //p->data = "OR"
            truth_vals = count_children(values, p->left_child);
            return (truth_vals.first >= 1);
            //return true if there is at least one true

        case 4: //p->data = "NOT"
            return !(evaluate(values, p->left_child));
            //return the inverse of what is obtained by evaluating the subtree

        default: //p->data = some number
            //in this case, we're just at a node with an index in it
            return values[atoi((p->data).c_str())];
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: the result of the recursive evaluation function should be a list of values, not (necessarily) a single value.

Comment: Well, it does have to return a bool eventually, though I see what you're getting at. I've been toying with that idea - if I could get a vector or something with 3 and 4 in it up to that AND I suppose that would be helpful. If I were to add a list of some kind as a parameter to the function, and passed it by reference, then... I could add the value when I got to the bottom and build that list on the way back up? That would probably work, but am I going to have issues with multiple recursive calls looking at the same list?

Comment: The top-level function invokes the recursive case on the root, asserts that the returns list contains only one element, and returns it. Everything else RETURNS a list. It doesn't pass in a list by reference. There are optimizations which you can do afterward, but first get it working.

Comment: Start by implementating the leaf case, then work your way up. And follow @Sneftel's advice.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still a bit confused. Are you saying I should be writing a helper function (or maybe more than one for different operators) that returns a list? Then, the original function, when it has that completed list, with one element, can return the one value in that list?

Comment: If you need to return a list, then your datastructure is not helping you much, no? Anyway, that approach needs to include a step which reduces a list to a single value, based on the operation, and if you can do that, you might as well do it in the recursion on the list of children rather than constructing a new list of evaluated children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive evaluation of an expression tree involves:

- evaluating each node of the tree

which in turn requires:

- applying an operation to a list of children (operands).

Now, let's try to be slightly systematic. Consider the operations you have -- `NOT`, `AND`, `OR` and `MAJ` -- and think about how to compute the value of each one over a list of operands. Specifically, what do we need to know about the list? In all cases, the following two data are sufficient (in only one case are both necessary):

- how many of the list's values are `TRUE`?
- how many of the list's values are `FALSE`?

(Alternatively, the second could have been "how many values are there in the list?", which is obviously equivalent.)

Then `AND` is `TRUE` iff the number of `FALSE` children is 0; `OR` is `FALSE` iff the number of `TRUE` children is 0; `MAJ` is `TRUE` iff the number of `TRUE` children is greater than the number of `FALSE` children. (There are at least two generalizations of `NOT` to a list of operands, or you could restrict it to the case where the number of `TRUE` children is 0 and the number of `FALSE` children is 1.)

Now, suppose we've reduced a list to those two values, `nTRUE` and `nFALSE`, and we want to add a new element to the list (that would be the recursion step.) Can we do that? Obviously.  If the new element is `TRUE`, we increment `nTRUE`; if the new element is `FALSE`, we increment `nFALSE`. Voilà!

In C++, the standard way of representing a pair of values is `std::pair`. Using that, we can express our recursive reduction as follows:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Counts;

Counts count(Tree_Node* node) {
  if (!node) return Counts{0, 0};
  Counts rest = count(node->right_sibling);
  if (evaluate(node))
    return Counts{rest.first + 1, rest.second};
  else
    return Counts{rest.first, rest.second + 1};
}
```

That assumes that `evaluate` returns a boolean. But we could make this even more elegant if evaluate returned a `Counts` object, using `{1,0}` to represent true and `{0,1}` to represent false. Then we could write:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> Counts;
Counts operator+(const Counts& a, const Counts& b) {
  return {a.first + b.first, a.second + b.second};
}

Counts count(Tree_Node* node) {
  if (!node)
    return Counts{0, 0};
  else
    return evaluate(node) + count(node->right_sibling);
}
```

In both cases, I've left out the definition of `evaluate`, which needs to vary depending on the operator. But I hope it is obvious how `evaluate(node)` uses `count(node->left_child)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the structure, on each subtree you have the operator at the root, first operand as the left child of the root and subsequent operands as right links from the
first operand, is that right?

Then the general scheme of evaluation would look like:

```
bool evaluate(const vector<bool> &values, Tree_Node* p) {
    bool result; 
    switch (p->op) {
        case BASE:
            return values[p->index];
        ...
        case AND:
            result = true;
            for (op = p->left; op != nullptr; op = op->right)
               result &= evaluate (values, op);
            return result;
        ...
    }
}
```

(Here I assumed the leaves contain indices in the `value` array.